# Graphviz how to fix the x pos of clusters

Tags: graphviz, subgraph

[image: Graphviz image]

Currently, I'm trying to fix the x Pos of clusters as they seem to move around creating a cluttered graph. All the sub-graph got `rank=same` and `newrank=true`. `constraint` value is set to `true` only for edges going from one cluster to another.

Tried many options from http://martin-loetzsch.de/S-DOT/constraint.html and couldn't get it to work. Does anyone know why the sub-graphs get moved horizontally like above?

```
// layered_view
digraph layered_view {
    bgcolor=transparent fontsize=8 nodesep=0.2 rankdir=TB splines=ortho
    switch_1 -> lake [label="" color=gold4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_1 -> lake [label="" color=chartreuse4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_1 -> switch_2 [label="" color=gold4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_1 -> switch_2 [label="" color=chartreuse4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_1 -> azure_1 [label="" color=gold4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_1 -> azure_1 [label="" color=chartreuse4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_2 -> watson [label="" color=goldenrod4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    lake -> tsX [label="" color=chartreuse4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    lake -> ptX [label="" color=chartreuse4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_1 -> dropBox [label="" color=chartreuse4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_1 -> ptX [label="" color=gold4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_1 -> tsX [label="" color=goldenrod4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    switch_1 -> watson [label="" color=goldenrod4 constraint=True dir=both style=solid]
    // software
    subgraph cluster_software {
        bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Software newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
        // applications
        subgraph cluster_applications {
            bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Applications newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
            tsX [label=tsX color=black fillcolor=chartreuse1 fixedsize=true shape=rectangle style=filled width=1.3 xlabel=""]
            ptX [label=ptX color=black fillcolor=chartreuse1 fixedsize=true shape=rectangle style=filled width=1.3 xlabel=""]
        }
        // cloud
        subgraph cluster_cloud {
            bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Cloud newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
            azure_1 [label=azure_1 color=black fillcolor=darkolivegreen1 fixedsize=true shape=rectangle style=filled width=1.3 xlabel=""]
            dropBox [label=dropBox color=black fillcolor=darkolivegreen1 fixedsize=true shape=rectangle style=filled width=1.3 xlabel=""]
        }
    }
    // systems
    subgraph cluster_systems {
        bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Systems newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
        // computing
        subgraph cluster_computing {
            bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Computing newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
            "ex-uni" [label="ex-uni" color=black fillcolor=cadetblue fixedsize=true shape=rectangle style=filled width=1.3 xlabel=""]
        }
        // sensors
        subgraph cluster_sensors {
            bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Sensors newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
            watson [label=watson color=black fillcolor=blue fixedsize=true shape=rectangle style=filled width=1.3 xlabel=""]
        }
        // storage
        subgraph cluster_storage {
            bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Storages newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
            lake [label=lake color=black fillcolor=deepskyblue2 fixedsize=true shape=rectangle style=filled width=1.3 xlabel=""]
        }
    }
    // network
    subgraph cluster_network {
        bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Network newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
        // switch
        subgraph cluster_switch {
            bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Switch newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
            switch_1 [label=switch_1 color=black fillcolor=gold fixedsize=true shape=rectangle style=filled width=1.3 xlabel=""]
        }
    }
    // artifacts
    subgraph cluster_artifacts {
        bgcolor=green color=black concentrate=true fontsize=8 label=Artifacts newrank=true rank=same splines=ortho
        switch_2 [label=switch_2 color=black fillcolor=white fixedsize=true shape=rectangle style=filled width=1.3 xlabel=""]
    }
}
```

Comment: would you share the .gv file?

Comment: @sroush have added the dot file content.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a straight-forward way to easily move clusters around.  Here is kludge that does what you want (I think) and does not take too much fiddling of the source:

1. comment out all your edges with /* ... */ (the edges are causing the non-alignment)
2. add these lines at the end (to produce the alignment you want):

> ```
> switch_1 -> switch_2  -> watson [style=invis]  
> watson -> {azure_1 tsX}         [style=invis]
> ```

3. run **dot** with **-Tdot** for the output file format
4. edit the output file and reinsert the edges you commented out
5. run neato with -n option to pin the nodes & clusters and add the edges

> neato -n -Tpng mylile.dot >myfile.png

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I am after a general solution as it needs to work with more nodes.